# Oauth 2.0 library for TomCat

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm searching for a library for the Oauth 2.0 protocol in TomCat. Although I'm searching very hard, I can't find anything.

I don't want Google system, or others provider, I just want a library that can help me to build MY OWN authentication and authorization system. In particolar I'd like to build the server-side of this protocol. 
Then, in the future, I'd like to integrate it with social login, but I want always my own system.

So, the answer is, is there any library to help doing this? Or I have to do it from scratch?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think there are several Java libraries for working with OAuth.  Have you Googled this?

Comment: Sura man, I have googled a lot. I want the server side of the Oauth protocol, so I need the Oauth 2.0 provider, but I really can't find something helpful.
If you know some libraries, you would make my day.

Comment: The exact implementation you use might depend on the service (e.g. Facebook vs. Google).

Comment: Your first challenge is to master Google and find the appropriate libraries. Only then will you be ready to actually use them. Programming is harder than using a search engine after all.

Comment: I know that, man. I was implementing it from scratch, following the RFC by ietf. But I think it is more "secure" using something already tested. I only found one library that I suppose could help me: Oltu by apache.

I'd like to know if someone used it and if he found some examples on Google. 
Thanks.